# Algebra rearranging

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm stuck on a question that should be extremely easy. The idea is to show that
$$\frac{\frac{n}{z}y + a}{y + \frac{z}{n}a} = \frac{n}{z}$$

What is the best method here?

Thanks

Comment: multiply the top and bottom by $nz$ and distribute.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Assuming that $z\ne 0\ne n$, the desired equation is equivalent to

$$z\left(\frac{n}zy+a\right)=n\left(y+\frac{z}na\right)\;,$$

as you can see by multiplying both sides by $nz$. (And you can make that assumption, because otherwise the expressions are undefined.)

Comment: I see, thank you very much!

Comment: @william: You’re most welcome!

Answer (score 1):

by using the long division you will get what you want
[image]

Comment: Note: I didn't downvote this. Still, as stated this would be more a comment than an answer. To make it a proper answer you should work out what you suggest, especially because the OP seems to be stuck on this problem.

Comment: @A.P. thank for your comment

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, it is easiest to work with simple fractions as opposed to nested fractions.  (In otherwords, try to make it in the form $\frac{A}{B}$ instead of in the form $\dfrac{~~\frac{a}{b}~~}{~~\frac{c}{d}~~}$)

$\begin{align}
\frac{\frac{n}{z} y+ a}{y+\frac{z}{n}a} &= \frac{~\frac{nz}{1}~}{~\frac{nz}{1}~}\frac{\frac{n}{z} y+ a}{y+\frac{z}{n}a}&~~\text{by multiplication by "one"}\\
& = \frac{n^2y+nza}{nzy+z^2 a}\\
& = \frac{n(ny+za)}{z(ny+za)} & \text{by factoring out common multiples}\\
& = \frac{n}{z} & \text{by cancelling common factors}
\end{align}$

Comment: That's very clear, thank you

Comment: One of the biggest tricks and things to learn about simplifying expressions is that you can always "multiply by *one*" and "add *zero*" and it will never change the truth of the expression.  The trick is what "one" and "zero" look like.